# Where do I get the widget that displays my ranking on all SE network sites?

Tags: support, reputation, flair, combined-flair, widgets

I noticed a widget on Jeff Atwood's website that displays his ranking on all sites on the Stack Exchange network.

Where can I get this widget from?

Answer (score 3):

Go to [your user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) (click your profile picture/rep/badges section in the header), then click on the [Settings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) tab. Under the "Site Settings" section on the left side of the page, click the link labeled "Flair".

On that page, there are two textboxes at the very bottom containing HTML code. The first one is site-specific for the site you're viewing; the second one is across all Stack Exchange sites (which is the one Jeff's website had).

You can also right-click on any of the flair images at the top of the screen to download it; however, if you use the URL that is provided in the HTML code, the flair will autoupdate.

Answer (score 3):

There's no longer a 'Got Flair?' thing.

You should go to your network profile page, and look under the tab 'flair'.

`https://stackexchange.com/users/<userID>/<username>?tab=flair`